# method of debugging large application outside of IDE

Tags: java, debugging, ant

I am used to having an application that compiles and runs within a Spring or Eclipse environment. This is how I know how to debug it. With a large application that requires ANT scripts to build it, and even though it compiles without errors, I cannot get it to build without errors.

So I was told I can go into a specific jar file which is an empty jar it seems, and add any classes I want with intended code changes and then monitor the logs to debug the changes. I find this a very tedious approach. Is anyone familiar with this? I end up putting compiled classes into the jar just using winrar and then run the application. Find this a weird way to do things but am able now to trace the code a bit. My question is whether this a systematic way to debug or do I need to figure out how to build it the ANT scripts and run it?

EDIT

Build error:

```
  BUILD FAILED

 C:\Users\me\Documents\SampleProjectJava\build.xml:41: taskdef class 
  tr.ant.SvnExport cannot be found
   using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

Total time: 0 seconds

Will add more details shortly.

Comment: doesn't ant print error message?

Comment: I'm confused: if it *compiles*, what kind of errors are you getting during build?

Comment: It has some build tasks that need an additional build jar. It seems complicated to me and I cannot get any assistance on how to build it. Will edit my question with some details on the build. But I get it that you both recommend going with the full build?